# Crawler для определенного сайта, генерирующего огромное кол-во однотипных ссылок

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, web-scraping, crawling

Мне нужно **своевременно** индексировать новые URL-адреса определенного сайта. Применяемый язык: **Python**.

Нужные мне URL-адреса, которые генерируется с большой скоростью:

- `example.com/a/show/52321024`
- `example.com/a/show/52321025` *(+1)*
- `example.com/a/show/52321026` *(+1)*

URL-адреса, которые не успели обзавестись контентом, выдают ошибку 404. Например:

- `example.com/a/show/52371026`.

Помимо индексации и проверки валидности URL, мне **приходится парсить содержимое страницы для дальнейших нужд**.

Я сам малоопытный в этом деле и наперед обозначил проблемы, которые не представляю как решить:

- Не совсем представляю как **правильно** создать пул валидных URL-адресов, которым будет кидаться request.
- Скорость генерации новых URL довольная большая. Примерно 1-3 новых страниц в секунду
- Учитывая такую скорость генерации новых страниц, парсер, который я планировал реализовать на BeautifulSoup, нуждается в бОльших ресурсах. **Может я применяю неправильный метод?**

Проблема, которую я решил проигнорировать:

- Некоторым новым страницам присваиваются отстающие по номеру URL-адреса. Для индексации этих страниц ничего не приходит в голову.

**Прошу вас поделиться правильным истолкованием решения проблемы. Заранее благодарю.**

У самого есть опыт парсинга с помощью BeautifulSoup библиотеки.

Comment: Прошу прощения, оказывается несуществующие страницы выдают ошибку 404. Исправил вопрос

Comment: пожалуйста, заэкраньте url'ы в вопросе так, чтобы это не было похоже на рекламу сайта и не заставляло индексаторы делать лишнюю работу.

Comment: 1 - собирайте все урлы в set - тогда дублирующихся записей не будет. 2 - для урлов можно делать HEAD запрос (это по сути тот же GET, только без отдачи содержимого), чтобы сразу получить статус урла (200 или 404, например). Те для которых придет 404 - те убрать из set'а.